# Integrating Alfresco and Liferay to show only one folder

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis

I'm trying to integrate Alfresco and Liferay. I have configured CMIS integration following [this guide](https://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository). It works without problem.

But now, I want to configure that repository to show only one folder. I can set a start folder on "Document and Media Portlet", but if I try to add a folder of the Alfresco repository, it says that there are not folders.

Here is a screenshot of "Document and Media portlet" integrated with an Alfresco repository

[image: Document and Media connected with Alfresco]

And this is when I try to select one folder of the repository

[image: Documents And Media repository config]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the latest versions of Alfresco, LifeRay and the LifeRay-Alfresco connector?

Comment: I'm using Alfresco Community 4.2.e and Liferay Community 6.2 GA2. The CMIS connector is bundled with this Liferay version.

Comment: Hey @rubenfa, seems to me like a bug in the product. I checked with the team, and it's supposed to work the way you mention. I'd suggest filing an issue on https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel

Comment: Thanks for your help @jbalsas. If it is a bug, I think it can be related with alfresco 4.2.e, because THE problem is reproduced with Liferay 6.1.1 and 6.2 GA1.

Comment: No problem, @rubenfa, actually, I found https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-46807 which seems to be exactly the same issue you described. If you're registered on our jira, you could watch that issue to be notified of its progress

Comment: @jbalsas why don't you add this comment as an answer? Looks like the ultimate solution.

Comment: I have to test one thing, because I had problems with Solr on Alfresco. CMIS queries weren't working, but this problem is solved after a reindex. Maybe the problem was here. If not, is probably that @jbalsas has found out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out where was the problem.

Alfresco's Solr indexes were corrupted. My CMIS queries were not working, so search documents within a folder by using CMIS, did not retuned results.

I have removed Solr Indexes, restarted Alfresco, and now Liferay is working without problem