# Indexing alfresco document using liferay

Tags: liferay, alfresco

I'm able to integrate alfresco document in liferay 
[Integrating Alfresco and Liferay to show only one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676281/integrating-alfresco-and-liferay-to-show-only-one-folder#)

but I'm unable to search the document content using search portlet, can I read the alfresco document content that were synced in liferay? Were they indexed?

Thanks

Comment: http://deepak-keswani.blogspot.fr/2012/07/how-to-rebuild-solr-indexes-in-alfresco.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to search Alfresco content from the native Liferay search portlet because Alfresco data are not indexed into Liferay Lucene indexes.

The only possibility is to used the document library search functionality which make search over a CMIS request.

Sincerely